# IOS Ad Hoc Distribution Adding devices

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I've created a Ad Hoc distribution profile with a couple of devices. If I want to add a couple of devices to the profile, I have to create a new profile and a build in XCODE for my app with the assigned profile.

Is there a way to make this easier? A way to make the management of the devices more simple? Without rebuilding and redistributing the app.

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the list of devices an ad-hoc app will work on without at least re-signing with xcode and redistributing the app. Sorry! I suppose Apple feel it opens up non-appstore distribution methods if you can add devices to an app already out there.

Comment: So if I read this right. It can't be done. I have to create a new profile and a new app build every time a add a new device?

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can!!

You **don't have to recompile your project again**. You don't even have to open XCode.

All you have to do is create a new mobileprovision file and distribute it with the existing app.

Your end users have to download and install the new mobileprovision file and app, by this order.

**Here is a [step-by-step](http://esrimobile.blogspot.pt/2012/12/on-my-previous-post-wrote-on-how-to.html).**

Hugo Maurício