# How to add device ids to ad hoc provisional profile without re-downloading?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

I'm part of a small group of friends who are iOS developers. We want to create a website where any one of us can upload their app and the rest of us can share it with our clients/acquaintances just to provide a feedback, before it hits the app store. We were planning to use ad hoc provisioning profile to achieve this. The problem is how to add device ids to the provisional profile without needing the original developer to re-download it from apple developer portal.

Note: We are willing to share our distribution certificate with each other

[Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399526/can-you-add-devices-to-an-ad-hoc-distribution-without-re-creating-the-ipa)

[Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384557/ios-ad-hoc-distribution-adding-devices)

Comment: TestFlight, which is designed to do just that. Fabric Beta might be another avenue, but each time a new device is added, you will need to register it and re-build the Appp

Comment: Fabric Beta needs the developer to add the new device UDIDs to the apple developer portal manually. I want to bypass that step.

Comment: Well, so do a million other developers :P